# Does graceful shutdown ensure node propagation of entries when writeSynchronizationMode is FULL_ASYNC?

Tags: ignite

I want to deploy Apache Ignite to our distributed system.

My question is whether graceful shutdown ensure node propagation of entries when writeSynchronizationMode is FULL_ASYNC or not.

For example, there are three nodes 1,2,3 and gracefully shutdown node 1 right after putting one entry to node 1 with FULL_ASYNC mode. In this situation has that entry been propagated to all nodes?

thank you in advance.

The entry is propagated to all appropriate nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot be assured that a write has propagated in FULL_ASYNC mode as the node receiving the master update acknowledges the write as successful once successful on that node. Anything that happens after that is an asyncronous update that may or may not happen in unusual circumstances such as node shutdown. If you need that assurance then you need to switch to FULL_SYNC.